# Show the stationary distribution of $\partial_tp=\partial_x(bp)+(1/2)\sigma^2\partial_{xx}p$ (forward Kolmogorov) is $p=Ce^{-2\int b/\sigma^2dx}$

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to understand this proof so that I can do the exercises without having to actually memorise the formula and plug in numbers, like a lot of people do. Thanks a lot in advance!

So if we have the forward Kolmogorov equation $\partial_t p=\partial_x(bp)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\partial_{xx}p$, we can get the stationary distribution by solving
$$\partial_x(bp)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\partial_{xx}p=0.$$
This leads to $bp+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\partial_{x}p=C_1=0$ when the vanishing boundary condition at $\infty$ is assumed.

**This is what I don't understand.**

Separating variables
$$p=p_s(x)=C_2e^{-2\int\frac{b}{\sigma^2}dx},$$
where $C_2$ is a constant.

**How did it get there though?**

Comment: There should not be an $x$ in the integrand inside the exponential. Nor in the title to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I've just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
bp+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\partial_{x}p = 0
$$
$$
2bp+\sigma^2\partial_{x}p = 0
$$
$$
\sigma^2\partial_{x}p = -2bp
$$
$$
\frac{1}{p}\,\partial_{x}p = -\frac{2b}{\sigma^2}
$$
$$
\partial_{x}\left(\ln p\right) = -\frac{2b}{\sigma^2}
$$
$$
\ln p(x) = \ln p(A) - \int_{A}^{x}\frac{2b}{\sigma^2}\,dx'
$$
where $A$ is a constant
$$
p = p(A)\,\exp\left(- \int_{A}^{x}\frac{2b}{\sigma^2}\,dx'\right)
$$

Now let $C \equiv p(A)$.

Comment: Oh crap, I feel so dumb that I didn't see that $\partial_x \ln p=\frac{\partial_x p}{p}$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Happens to everyone once in a while. Thanks for accepting my answer.